# How to apply custom validation on a field using javax validation only if it is not null?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, hibernate-validator

I am working on javax validation API in Spring Boot Application. I have a User bean and i have to validate that username given in request is unique and doesn't exist into Database.

I have created custom annotation (`UniqueUser.java`) and custom Validator(`UniqueUserValidator.java`) for this requirement.

```
public class User  {
    @NotNull
    @UniqueUser
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String phone;
}
```

**UniqueUser.java**

```
@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUserValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface NameMatch
{
    String message() default "User id already exists";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**UniqueUserValidator.java**

```
public class UniqueUserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NameMatch, Object>
{
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
   
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String userName, final ConstraintValidatorContext context)
    {
        boolean isValidUser = false;
        if(userName!=null && !userName.isEmpty()) {
        Optional<User> user= userRepository.findByUserId(userName);
           isValidUser = !user.isPresent(); 
        }
        return isValidUser;
    }
}
```

In above code, the unique user validation get called for username field even if the field is null and shows Username already exists error message. I want the custom validator to get called only when username has some value. Is it possible to avoid this call.

I can fix the error by modifying the below method and returning true if username is null, but i want't to avoid this unnecessary call.

```
public class UniqueUserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NameMatch, Object>
{
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
   
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String userName, final ConstraintValidatorContext context)
    {
        boolean isValidUser = false;
        if(userName!=null && !userName.isEmpty()) {
        Optional<User> user= userRepository.findByUserId(userName);
           isValidUser = !user.isPresent(); 
        } else {
           isValidUser = true; 
        }
        return isValidUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to call ```if(userName!=null && !userName.isEmpty())```?

Comment: if you don't check in `isValid` then you have to check for null in somewhere to take the decision, then nothing exactly optimized actually. Your current implementation is fine

Comment: And rather use a custom annotation I love to use do this check  inside service since you are calling repository before controller which is not a good pattern at all , IMHO ofcourse.

Comment: Just a side note : I think you mean `public @interface UniqueUser` since you are using `@UniqueUser` in your DTO

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [Grouping constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html#chapter-groups);

> Groups allow you to restrict the set of constraints applied during
> validation. One use case for validation groups are UI wizards where in
> each step only a specified subset of constraints should get validated.
> The groups targeted are passed as var-arg parameters to the
> appropriate validate method.

In your case it should look like this:

```
@GroupSequence({ FirstConstaint.class, SecondConstaint.class })
public class User  {
    @NotNull(groups = FirstConstaint.class)
    @UniqueUser(groups = SecondConstaint.class)
    private String username;

    // the rest of your fields
}

interface FirstConstaint {
}

interface SecondConstaint {
}
```

This way, it will check `@UniqueUser` only if the field is not null, otherwise, it will return the message of  @NotNull validation.

Otherwise like @User said you can use this checks in service layer ^^